# Rsyslog is not saving logs from different networks correctly

Tags: database, rsyslog

I am trying to set up rsyslog server, that would save the logs into database. I coded web app easily maintain and search through logs. But I have multiple networks there (not at home, but in work obviously, so no changes here). And I have trouble saving logs from system from different networks. I have network 10.1.1.0/24, where is my rsyslog located (exactly it has IP: 10.1.1.130).

Here is the configuration I am using on SERVER:

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514" )

module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514" )

$template MariaDbTpl, "INSERT INTO SystemEvents (receivedAt, deviceTime, facility, priority, fromHost, syslogTag, message) VALUES ('%timegenerated:::date-mysql%', '%timereported:::date-mysql%', %syslogfacility%, %syslogpriority%, '%fromhost-ip%', '%syslogtag%', '%msg%')",SQL

$ModLoad ommysql
*.* action(type="ommysql" Server="127.0.0.1" ServerPort="3306" db="syslog" UID="user_syslog" PWD="<censored>" Template="MariaDbTpl")
```

And here is my client example:

```
*.* @10.1.1.130:514
```

I set up firewall correctly, as the connection was successfull from multiple networks. But I do not see any logs from different networks in my database. After digging up some hours I figured out, that the logs are inside in the local text file /var/log/messages, here I was able to find the logs from systems outside of 10.1.1.0/24 even from different networks 172.16.2.0/24, 172.16.3.0/24, 192.168.72.0/24, but not in the database. All of the messages from these hosts are located just in the file and not database. And just in case, here is the SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `SystemEvents` ( 
  `aid` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `receivedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `deviceTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `facility` SMALLINT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `priority` SMALLINT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `fromHost` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `syslogTag` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `message` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT `PRIMARY` PRIMARY KEY (`aid`, `receivedAt`)
);
```

All logs from systems located at 10.1.1.0/24 are here, every seconds there are tens of new logs, working like a charm. Just when I am trying to send it from system located in different network (I was able to check connection through netcat - linux & Test-NetConnection - windows , everything went through). What is exactly not working there? I could not find the fix for this issue after some days of searching through internet.